# Issues with cross-DLL access modifiers and cyclic dependency

Tags: oop, dll, c++-cli, factory, access-modifiers

I am developing a plugin for [Dynamo](https://dynamobim.org/) in C++/CLI (.NET), and I have a problem with method visibility.

Basically, Dynamo will parse a DLL, and all the public classes and methods will appear in the user interface, while private methods and other methods with the `IsVisibleInDynamo` attribute set to `false`, even if they are declared as public, will be hidden.

Now we are targeting the plugin for two sets of users: end users who will only use the plugin in Dynamo, and developers who might extend our plugin to create another library.

In the library, we have a set of classes, e.g. `Vertex`, and factories to create instances of these classes, e.g. `VertexFactory`. In order to create a `Vertex`, `VertexFactory::Create(...)` needs to be called, and it will create a `Vertex` by its constructor.

The `Vertex` class certainly needs to be public as it is used by both the end users and developers, however `VertexFactory` should be visible only to developers. Therefore, I declare methods in VertexFactory as public but set the `IsVisibleInDynamo` to true.

Currently our plugin is closely tied to Dynamo, however, I would like to split the plugin to two DLLs: one, say `PluginNET`, is the application-independent one, as we are starting to expand to other applications; and the other one, say `PluginDynamo`, provides Dynamo-related functionalities.

The factory classes need to go to `PluginNET`, however, I face a challenge in hiding these classes from Dynamo, because the `IsVisibleInDynamo` attribute is dependent on Dynamo.

What I am thinking of is to create yet another DLL, say `PluginFactories`, however, I am going to face a cyclic dependency, where the creation methods in `PluginNET` which will create `Vertex` etc need to refer to factory classes like `VertexFactory` in `PluginFactories`, but `PluginFactories` depend on the actual constructors in PluginNet.

Is there a more proper OOP mechanism/architecture to hide these classes, and whether anyone knows a better alternative to solve this problem?